# Prevent Yahoo! to ask me again about changing the theme

Tags: yahoo-mail

After the latest design changes (Metro style) when going to Y!Mail page, Yahoo asks me two things:

- to upgrade change my browser (I click "Continue without upgrading"):

  > [image]
- to personalize my inbox with a theme:

  > [image]

Even if I select my favorite theme and click the **Keep theme** button, *every time* Yahoo! asks me these questions again and again! It also forgets my selected theme.

Did anyone find a solution to this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have third-party cookies enabled?

Comment: Try changing it again from settings, _after_ you enter the app. Try choosing a different one from _Cog wheel_ → _Themes_ → choose one → click **Done** and see if remembers it this way.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise What's that? How can I enable them? I have cookies activated.

Comment: @Alex That didn't work for me... :-(

Comment: That’s strange, because these settings are stored server-side, so I suspect a glitch/bug. Try setting this from a different browser/computer.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise I don’t think it has anything to do with third-party cookies—I have them disabled and the themes work without a problem.

Comment: @Alex On Firefox I don't have this problem... Only on the Chromium. Also, the problem was solved for Chromium, too (after I selected the theme in Firefox). Thanks! Earn some points by giving a good answer. ;-)

Comment: You could also delete all the browser cookies. Sometimes, invalid data in cookies can cause problems.

Comment: @machineaddict Probably it's not an issue anymore. I switched to Gmail long time ago. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are stored server-side, so it’s probably just a glitch/bug. Try setting the theme from a different browser/computer.